# Chord symbol confusion

Tags: chords, notation

In this example, many chords are marked as major with a triangle or minor with a minus sign - for the ones that simply say, e.g "C#7" - what would they be?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chord symbols are very explicit in telling you what chord you are playing. A C♯7 is a C♯ dominant 7th spelled `C#, E#, G#, B`. Any chord with a note and a 7 is a dominant 7th.

Here's a simple breakdown of chords based on chord symbols. To keep this general, we'll use C as an example, but this is for any root note:

### Triads

- **C** = C major = root, major 3rd, perfect 5th
- **C-** = C minor = root, minor 3rd, perfect 5th
- **C<sup>o</sup>** = C diminished = root, minor 3rd, diminished 5th
- **C+**= C augmented= root, major 3rd, augmented 5th
- **Csus4** = C minor = root, perfect 4th, perfect 5th
- **Csus2** = C minor = root, major 2nd, perfect 5th

### Seventh chords

- **CΔ7** = C major 7th = root, major 3rd, perfect 5th, major 7th
- **C7** = C dominant 7th = root, major 3rd, perfect 5th, minor 7th
- **C-7** = C minor 7th = root, minor 3rd, perfect 5th, minor 7th
- **C-Δ7** = C minor major 7th = root, minor 3rd, perfect 5th, major 7th
- **C<sup>ø</sup>** = C half diminished = root, minor 3rd, diminished 5th, minor 7th
- **C<sup>o</sup>7** = C diminished 7th = root, minor 3rd, diminished 5th, diminished 7th
- **C+Δ7** = C augmented major 7th = root, major 3rd, perfect 5th, major 7th
- **C+7** = C augmented 7th = root, major 3rd, perfect 5th, minor 7th

There are way more chord symbols then this and there are variations on pretty much every chord symbol. This should get you started though.

Comment: Thanks guys, so for Roman Numeral Analysis - how does the chord being dominant affect your numeral?

Comment: @Dylan not every dominant chord is treated the same and there are different schools of thought on analysis. If it's a dominant 7th most of the time there will be a V7 in some way shape or form, but could also be a passing chord or serve a different function.